# Find the difference between two list

Tags: text-processing, diff, pip

I desire to compute the difference of two lists:

```
$ pip list > package1.md
Package                            Version  
---------------------------------- ---------
alabaster                          0.7.10   
anaconda-client                    1.6.9    
anaconda-navigator                 1.7.0    
anaconda-project                   0.8.2    
appnope                            0.1.0    
 ....

$ pip3 list > package2.md
Package                            Version  
---------------------------------- ---------
alabaster                          0.7.10   
anaconda-client                    1.6.9    
anaconda-navigator                 1.7.0    
anaconda-project                   0.8.2    
appnope    
...
```

To find the package installed in package1 but not in package 2.

How to accomplish such a task?

Comment: Fix your tags to remove `bash`. This is not a `bash` question, should be in text processing tag

Comment: you can use `pip list --format=freeze` to not have the header lines in the output; also you can easily store the freezed output to a file and install from the file later, via `pip install -r file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With **`comm`** command:

```
comm -23 <(sort package1.md) <(sort package2.md)
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed to do the right thing even though the data is not strictly speaking sorted?  I've tested it, and it works, but since `comm` requires sorted input, I'm not quite sure _why_ it works and whether it's _guaranteed_ to work.

Comment: @Kusalananda, it simply works cause `pip list` sorts the list, i.e. it does a part of work for us in this case

Comment: This _list_ is sorted, but the input to `comm` is not. The first two lines (the header) is not in lexicographical order (`-` comes before `P`).

Comment: Looking at the implementations of `comm` I have access to, it seems that it ought to work as long as the lines that are not sorted are identical in both files and as long as these lines are compared with each other and not otherwise offset from each other in the two files.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes, I've just played with some offsets and got `comm: file 1 is not in sorted order`.; an offset indeed matters. Updated

Comment: though I intentionally added lines in unsorted order when testing offsets, while `pip list` will sort them

Answer (score 0):

Use diff(1). You might want to preprocess with sort(1), and perhaps use tail(1) to cut off headers.